# LoRaWAN: What is a safe distance between two end devices using the same spreading factor that makes sure they don't interfere with one another?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I'm working on an algorithm with the help of a simulator that changes how end devices are distributed such that interference between end devices using the same spreading factor is minimized. I'm still learning about LoRaWAN, however, and I don't know what could be considered a safe distance between two end devices that would accomplish this.

Comment: why would there be a limit to the minimum distance between devices? ... there should be a mechanism for re-transmission of data if a collision occurs

Comment: The answer is probably related to the link budget equation.

Comment: Note that LoRaWAN transmissions over severelal hundred kilometres have been recorded, so I’m not sure there is any useful absolute distance over which there will be no interference.